# Batch file to open fortran compiler, set work directory and execute a command

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, fortran, abaqus

I'm trying to write a batch file which will open the cmd prompt, to open the fortran compiler. set my work directory and then input: abaqus cae noGUI="scriptname.py"

I'm doing this so I can call the batch file from MATLAB (so if anyone has a way of eliminating the batch file that's great too!)

so far I have:

```
@echo off "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Compiler\Fortran\9.1\EM64T\Bin\IFortVars.bat" intel64 & cd C:\Users\11424912\Documents\Abaqus\Rigid_Body_Example\2Blocks\Rigid\
```

And that won't input the work directory however the fortran compiler is opening! So I can't get it to input the directory. I can get it to open the work directory too in matlab using

```
 script = strcat('C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /K ""C:\Program Files       (x86)\Intel\Compiler\Fortran\9.1\EM64T\Bin\IFortVars.bat" & cd ',' "',dir,'"',' & abaqus CAE noGUI=',scripttitle,' & exit');
```

however that doesn't input the abaqus CAE noGUI. So I'm further in the MATLAB effort but not there on either. any help would be great thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the matlab function `system` http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html to cut out the middle man and run your command directly. You can use `sprintf` etc to customise the command string you pass to `system`.

You can also set the `PATH`, `LIB`, and `INCLUDE` variables permenantly in your enviroment file so that you don't have to run ifortvars every time (note sets it for every cmd window you open) see here http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/ Just rinse and repeat for the other 2 variables.

To see what gets set by ifortvars, you can look at the ifortvars bat file (and any other bat file it calls) or else use `echo %PATH%` to see what the path is set to after running ifortvars. This will tell you what to add to the `PATH` variable - similarly for `LIB` and `INCLUDE`